# Facebook API - news feed with wall posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am fetching a user's news feed using the Facebook API and displaying some of the data on a page. However, I am having trouble with wall posts. The data returned by the API considers a wall post to be a "status" update by the user posting, and the data does not include a field to say who the wall post is written to. Is it possible to query an item to check whether it is a wall post or not? Or is there a way I can receive the name of the recipient?

Here is the code I am using to fetch the user's news feed:

`FB.api('/me/home', function (response) { console.log(response) });`

A wall post will just give me `message` (content of the wall post) and `type` of `status`. For example:

If **Oliver** wrote on **John**'s wall, saying: "Hi", Facebook gives me:

```
{
    from: {
        name: "Oliver"
    },
    message: "Hi",
    type: "status"
}
```

There's nothing to tell me it is a wall post nor who the recipient is. The result does include some other arbitrary data but none of that helps (`id`, `created_time`, etc.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Facebook has made this topic overly confusing.  Just reading their documentation on the user object in the Graph API leaves you guessing: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

**/user/feed**  The user's wall.

<s>**/user/home**   The user's news feed.</s>

**UPDATED: */user/home* endpoint is now deprecated [07.06.2020], looks like there is no any possibility to get news feed now, see [graph api user news feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583256/graph-api-user-news-feed)**

**/user/statuses**  The user's status updates.

*Why they couldn't have the "wall" /user/wall and "news feed" /user/newsfeed "status updates" as /user/statusupdates to make is simple I will never know!*

So to get a list of status updates, do an HTTP Get to  `http://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token=ValidUserAccessToken` for the current user.

To get a list of wall stream items, do an HTTP Get to `http://graph.facebook.com/me/wall?access_token=ValidUserAccessToken` for the current user.

To get a list of home feed stream items, do an HTTP Get to `http://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=ValidUserAccessToken` for the current user.

When you come across the "from" and you wonder who it's to, it's "to" the user who's access token you're using when calling `/me/....` or if your calling with a specific ID `/UserId/...` then it will be the user id for the "to".

---

Another thought: Grab the complete object from the stream FQL table object (developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) and see if there's some information there that's not exposed via the Graph object.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I'm using `/me/home`, which gives me the user's news feed. In that news feed, it will show me wall posts between friends. In that case, the "to" is not the user who's access token I am using to make the call, but it also does not tell me who it is to. That is exactly my problem. If I'm **Bob**, I can see a wall post from **Oliver** to **John** in my news feed. But the API won't tell me it's to John. Does that make sense?

Comment: Grab the complete object from the stream FQL table object (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) and see if there's some information there that's not exposed via the Graph object.

Comment: FQL seems to be the way to go. The FQL response does tell you whether or not it is a wall post. Just means I have to refactor loads of my code… great, but thank you! If you could update your answer to mention FQL, I will tick it :)

Comment: Hmm, I've now got another problem upon my hands. The FQL does not provide me with the name of the user for each story in the stream, only `actor_id`. Does this mean I would have to make another FQL call to the API just to get the name of the actor, and then merge my results together? Seems long winded :/

Comment: The answer is yes, another call is in order (or do a multiquery).  However, you should stick with the one question/one answer format stackover is designed for.  Please ask new questions in a new question. Thanks :)