# graph api user news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

by calling /me/feed in graph api i can get feed  like my posts or posts that i am tagged in.

How can i get a feed with my  friends posts or news that i see in my wall in fb?

i mean feed like the one that i see when i login to facebook

```
i tryed me/feed with several parameters but no luck
```

same here 
     https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference no info :(

i didnt manage to find something useful in facebook graph api explorer

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> How can i get a feed with my friends posts or news that i see in my wall in fb?

You can’t.

That used to be available in the very beginning via the `/home` edge, but that has since been removed.

There is no replacement. Friend’s posts are only available to your app, if the friend would join your app and grant it permission to read their posts.

(Plus, platform policy says apps should not replicate Facebook “core functionality”. If a user wants their news feed, they can go to Facebook ...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i just show an app called friendly, i used it and  logged on with my fb credentials and i see in the app the feed that i am asking, i see posts from friends etc. How they made that?

Comment: @TeO not by using the API, or in any allowed way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but while they use fb login, the facebook will have give them the ok to use it. I am telling that, because when i upload an app to appStore, in order to make the fb login public, facebook reviewed my app and gave me the ok, otherwise only the developer could login. So how they use fb login , if they use a not legal way?

Comment: They might have hidden features from the reviewers, or only added them later on ...

Comment: thank you for your reply, so in my mind the only solution to display that info is by parsing/scraping the real facebook page after they logged in with my credentials, do you know another way?

Comment: No there is no other way. And Facebook Terms of Service and Facebook Platform Policy both makes it not allowed to give away your username/password or ask for username/password